# How to VLOOKUP an Excel Table in another Excel sheet

Tags: excel, office365, vlookup

I am trying to `VLOOKUP` a value in an Excel Table and get the value from another Excel Table in another sheet.
the first table is called `PRODUCTS` and the second one is called `PRODUCT DETAILS`
In `PRODUCTS` I have:

```
GTIN-13 | SKU | NAME | PRICE
```

In `PRODUCT DETAILS` I have:

```
GTIN-13 | SKU | NAME | GW | NW
```

From `PRODUCT DETAILS` I am trying to Vlookup `SKU` from `PRODUCTS` and get the `GTIN-13` value into `PRODUCT DETAILS`

`GTIN-13 (PRODUCT DETAILS)`: `=VLOOKUP([@SKU],PRODUCTS,1,)`

But formula return `#N/A`.

I can't understand where I am mistaken

Comment: Please take time to write your question clearly, from the question in its present form it is not entirely clear where are you trying to get the value from and put into what table.

Comment: Do you mean `([@[SKU]],...`?  If you step through the formula in the Formula Evaluator, can you see where it's going wrong/why it's returning the error?

Comment: Firstly, if you want to use SKU values to fetch the corresponding GTIN-13 values from PRODUCTS, then SKU column should be located on the left and GTIN-13 on the right.

Comment: So, in PRODUCTS, try moving SKU as the leftmost column that should hopefully solve the #N/A problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PRODUCTS` table, move SKU column to the leftmost of the table. So column order will be as below:
`SKU | GTIN-13 | NAME | PRICE`

In `PRODUCT DETAILS` table, use the below formula:
`=VLOOKUP([@SKU],PRODUCTS,2,FALSE)`

In this `VLOOKUP` formula, the number 2 indicates that you are trying to fetch the value from 2nd column (i.e. `GTIN-13` is the 2nd col in `PRODUCTS`) when there is a match on `SKU` in the first column (VLOOKUP always tries to match values in the first column of your search range) in `PRODUCTS`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` only works when the common column in both the table is on the left side of the desired values column.

You can just change the `SKU` column position to the left of `GTIN-13` column and your formula will work fine.

Now if you don't want to tamper with the data tables and want more powerful lookup function, then you can use `INDEX` & `MATCH` functions.

[image]

`INDEX` takes 3 values - `INDEX(Table, Row, Column)`

`MATCH` takes 3 values - `MATCH(Cell, Column, [-1, 0, 1])` ---- Here `0` is used to find the exact match

Now if you combine the both functions you can replace the `Row` of `INDEX` with the `MATCH` function.

It will be like this - `INDEX(Table, MATCH(Cell, Column, 0), Column)`

My formula in the sheet is `INDEX(I:J, MATCH(D2, J:J, 0), 1)`

Here I have used 1 as the `Column` of `INDEX` because I wanted the values of `GTIN-13`.